# How to change css file of bx-slider, multiple sliders on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

i'm developing a website with bx slider.

i need three sliders on a page for slide html content.

i have added a bx slider on page and customized it with css. i made changes in jquery.bxslider.css

now i'm adding another bx slider on a page. but it applies the css i modified on that new slider too. so i want to change CSS of the new added slider but not which one i modified. so as i think it needs two css files.

i tried css with nth-child but not working, it applies on both sliders.

so, how can i change css files in bx-slider ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just have to add class to each different bx-slider. You do not need 2 separate CSS files.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="bxslider one"></ul>
<ul class="bxslider two"></ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.bxslider.one {
    background: blue;
}
.bxslider.two{
    background: red;
}
```

If this is not working you can create a container for your bx-sliders and target the `bx-wrapper` class within:

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider-one">
    <ul class="bxslider"></ul>
</div>
<div class="slider-two">
    <ul class="bxslider"></ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider-one .bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
    background: blue;
}
.slider-two .bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Not working bro,
the background of bx-slider is bx-wrapper

Comment: This is the correct answer. You just apply the .bxslider() to $('.bxslider') in your jQuery

Comment: i need different styling in each bx-slider. its not about jquery. its about css.
both sliders have bx-wrapper class which responsible for slider background and it generates by jquery, not by markup. so its not correct answer sorry.

Comment: I've updated my answer to target the `bx-wrapper` class.

Comment: i have added .bx-viewport class in css and it works !